# Promise.all resolving prematurely

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want to `fetch` multiple JSON files. Here's my code:

```
var timestamps = [];
var urls = ['assets/layouts/default.json','assets/layouts/simple.json'];
var jsons = [];
Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
  fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(json => {
    jsons.push(json);
    timestamps.push(performance.now());
  });
}))
.then(() => {
  console.log(`All assets loaded. Assets were loaded at: ${timestamps}, this log was made at ${performance.now()}. Loaded data: ${jsons}`);
}
);
```

The problem is that the `Promise.all` seems to resolve prematurely. As you can see I included some debugging, it logs this:

```
All assets loaded. Assets were loaded at: , this log was made at 37.73. Loaded data:
```

If I wrap that `console.log` in a `setTimeout` and save the time when `Promise.all` is resolved like so:

```
.then(() => {
  let promiseResolvedAt = performance.now();
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`All assets loaded. Assets were loaded at: ${timestamps}, Promise.all was resolved at ${promiseResolvedAt}. Loaded data: ${jsons}`);
  })
}
```

I get this:

```
All assets loaded. Assets were loaded at: 63.44000000000001,63.555, Promise.all was resolved at 55.96500000000001. Loaded data: [object Object],[object Object]
```

I can get it to work like I want it to by using `setTimeout` but I'm sure there is a better way and I'm just doing something wrong here.

Why does the `Promise.all` resolve before it's component promises resolve?

I'm running this on Chrome 55.

Comment: Remove the `{` `}` around the `fetch` statement to allow for implicit return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise:

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => {
      jsons.push(json);
      timestamps.push(performance.now());
    });
}))
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body:

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit
>   return is attached. **In a block body, you must use an explicit `return`
>   statement**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the calls to `fetch` when mapping the array of URLs, otherwise your `Promise.all(...)` is waiting on `[undefined, undefined]`, which will resolve immediately, as you observed.

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
   return fetch(url)
// ^^^^^^
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(json => {
      jsons.push(json);
      timestamps.push(performance.now());
    });
}))
```